# The construction with んじゃないかな

Tags: grammar

> リビングが広いのはいいと思うけど、駐車場が付いてた方がいい**んじゃない**かな。

"Although I like it that the living room is spacious, I guess an attached parking space *would be great*." Do I understand the sentence right?

Why is んじゃない　used here?

Can we say "...駐車場が付いてた方がいいでしょう" to mean the same thing?

Comment: It implies that there is no parking nearby, and politely suggest that I may refuse to take this one, because of this. The phrase makes it more politely. And your suggestion sounds very wired, it feels like that the speaker is giving order to the listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`んじゃないかな` is softer than `いいでしょう`. For example, suppose I'm talking to a senpai of me with whom I can use タメ語 because we are very close. I would still avoid saying `駐車場が付いてた方がいいでしょう` because it implies I'm pretty sure it should have a parking (and insult the senpai by suggesting I can be pretty sure about a topic which he cannot be). `駐車場が付いてた方がいいんじゃないかな` would be a suggestion ("maybe a parking wouldn't hurt?") and hence avoids this potential offence.

In a different context, your phrase is perfectly valid. For example, a MIL may say: "リビングが広いのはいいと思うけど、駐車場が付いてた方がいいでしょう" because it is accepted that MILs can generally make better decisions because of their seniority (life experience).